# Retrieving beacon attachments proximity beacon api

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

Currently I have registered beacons to the Google Proximity Beacon API. They're Eddystone beacons. I can also retrieve the beacon's data and add attachment (I think).  The problem I have is retrieving those attachments.

I used the following website to retrieve the attachments, but I get a 404 error in return.
https://labs.ribot.co.uk/exploring-google-eddystone-with-the-proximity-beacon-api-bc9256c97e05#.rndagn22e

```
<a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
<p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
<p>The requested URL <code>/v1beta/beaconName/attachments/</code> was not found on this server.  
<ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I used a GET method to retrieve the data. My application sends the request with a token using a Volley JsonObjectRequest. This is the URL I am using:

GET https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beaconName/attachments

If I use the GET method to retrieve the beacons I do also not recieve the attachments (I can't find it anywhere if it should return the attachments as well).

Is it possible that I use the wrong URL? Has anyone else come across the same problem?

*EDIT*:
I updated my url with the query parameter required:

```
https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta/beaconName/attachments?namespacedType=*/*
```

In the request headers I put the token I retrieved from a previous request (oAuth2.0). There's no API key involved here. Every other method for updating, registering and retrieving beacons work, except for retrieving attachments.

*SOLVED*
There was a 1 missing in the URL

```
https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beaconName/attachments?namespacedType=*/*
```

Comment: It's hard to come up with an answer without seeing the code.  What exact response do you get from `GET https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beaconName/attachments`?  And are you using an API key?

Comment: I am using a JsonObjectRequest. In the header of the request I put a token I retrieved from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method. The response I receive from GET https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beaconName/attachments is the 404 error I posted in my question. I am not using an API key (that shouldn't be the problem since the other calls work)

Comment: is your beacon name really "beaconName"?

Comment: No, it has a beacons/N!beaconid name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta/beaconName/attachments?namespacedType=*/*
```

The above URL is missing a 1 after v1beta, it's supposed to be v1beta1 as written in de URL below.

```
https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beaconName/attachments?namespacedType=*/*
```